# Wake network adapter from deep sleep mode

Tags: network-adapter

I recently buyed a new Mainboard (Asrock ALiveXFire) and got some trouble with the network adapter. After switching my Windows 7 x64 in energey saving mode and returning from it, my network adapter couldn't be found.

After some googling I found out, that apparently my network adapter has been put in a deep sleep mode and didn't reactivate. Their solution was to switch the PC off, take out the RAM and the CMOS battery for some time. After that, the adapter should be powered on again, but that didn't happen for me. I waited several hours before turning my PC on again, but that didn't help.

Formatting and reinstalling didn't help either.

The network adapter is not found in the hardware manager and reinstalling the drivers didn't help. I have the newest BIOS installed on the mainboard.

I literally don't know what to try next. I'm thinking of returning my board, but I would like to avoid the hassle.

Comment: To be honest with you it sounds like a bad NIC. What makes you think it is in a 'deep sleep mode'?

Comment: After installing new drivers I got a message asking if the network adapter is in deep sleep mode and [several](http://adeelejaz.com/blog/realteks-network-controller-deep-sleep-mode-issue/) [other](http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/19488-no-ethernet-controller-no-internet-connection.html) websites came up with the same problem. But their solution didn't work for, so I came her

Comment: " I got a message asking if the network adapter is in deep sleep mode" is not the same thing as an indication that it *is* in that mode.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem like this:
 - Disable Intel SpeedStep (if any) in BIOS

After I did that Windows just installed the driver when I booted the next time.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some bad drivers which cause network and other devices to not wake up from advanced power states, but I have never heard the solution of taking out RAM and battery.

Quite frankly, a restart should always reset the devices and the fact that it hasn't makes me think that it is faulty or damaged.

If I was you, I would also check the BIOS/EFI quickly to see if it has accidentally been disabled or similar.